# Default folder for PuTTY (Windows) to pickup the private key

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, authentication

I have a private key file that I use to login to my AWS instances everytime by opening

> putty -> SSH -> auth

and mentioning the private key file (ppk).

Is there a folder or some setting on Windows PuTTY where placing this file will be picked up by default or some equivalent client which can help resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

After selecting the key file, go back to the first page; select "Default Session"; then click "Save". Everything that you've configured (key path, username, port...) will be saved as defaults.

If a key was saved to "Default Session", it'll be used when you run `putty user@example.com`. If instead you saved it to a custom session, `putty -load MySession user@example.com` will use that.

Alternatively, load the .ppk file into Pageant (which is PuTTY's equivalent of ssh-agent), by double-clicking it or dropping it into the `shell:startup` folder. All keys loaded into Pageant will be automatically used by PuTTY and WinSCP no matter which session you load.

---

Windows also comes with OpenSSH – the `ssh` command – which has its own configuration in the `~/.ssh/config` file and its own ssh-agent where you can load keys via `ssh-add` (and remembers the loaded keys across reboots, unlike the Linux version), but by default it will look for private keys at `~/.ssh/id_rsa` plus a few other similar names (id_ed25519, id_ecdsa, etc.)